# Clientside GitHub Authentication

Tags: javascript, github-api

I'm using a Javascript to do Basic Authentication with GitHub. For example, the following shell command gets a token from Github:

```
    curl -i -u uaername:password -k -d "{\"scopes\": [\"repo\"]}" https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

How do you achieve that with jQuery and AJAX?

Answer (score 7):

### Including Basic Auth Data in HTTP Headers with jQuery

You can include *basic auth* details in the header using the `Authorization` field. You already understand how jQuery works. This snippet has the bits you're missing:

```
    let auth = btoa(username + ":" + password);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ...,
        headers: { Authorization: "Basic " + auth }
        ...
    });
```

Note: `btoa` and `atob` (pronounced *B to A* and *A to B*) are builtin functions, and convert to and from [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) for more information.

Comment: useful snippet too if you are using a personal access token, thanks

Comment: Is this safe to do in client-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking whether there is a way to get an oAuth token purely from the client side? If so, the answer is no.

But, you have some work arounds.

Github.js: https://github.com/michael/github

Gatekeeper is an open source server side component which can help with oAuth tokens management:

https://github.com/prose/gatekeeper

You could also use something like Firebase with simple login and in this case you don't need to manage any server side services:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-github.html

Comment: He asked specifically about basic auth, which you can definitely do from a browser. There's Octokit JS libraries that do it.

Comment: Yes, this is correct that he asked about basic auth, but I don't think you can use basic auth to retrieve an oAuth token (I think he needs that here, no?), even with these libraries. I believe you have to map the callback to an actual server (not just a web browser) which means the pure client side JS won't work.

Comment: No. You can just include the username and password in the request headers. You never *need* oAuth.