# How to perform 2 factor authentication to GitHub with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, github

I want to query GitHub to get all the open pulls. I've never attempted anything like this before, and as I'm on my own, I have no colleagues I can ask for guidance. The only help so far has been the documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319551/1221410 shows how to provide my username and password. However, the GitHub repo has two-factor authentication.

The relevant part of the GitHub doc (I think) is

> In addition to the Basic Authentication credentials, you must send the user's authentication code (i.e., one-time password) in the X-GitHub-OTP header

I have created a personal access token and my code looks like

```
const auth = getAuth();
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/company/repo/pulls",            
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        headers: { 
            "Authorization": "Basic " + auth,
            "X-GitHub-OTP": "d......Access...Token.......5"
        },
...
```

The above always returns a fail with the following message

> Must specify two-factor authentication OTP code.

I thought I had in the header. I'm not sure what I've done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X-GitHub-OTP` header is for a *one time password*, the 6 digit code you get from your Authenticator app or via SMS when you log in. It's not for an API token.

Comment: Right. I understand now. In that case, I need to probably go down the oAuth route! Thank you